# Ubuntu server and Java

Tags: 12.04, java

I'm trying to host a Runescape private server on one of my old dell machines and i'm just about to install java now...Should i install JRE or JDK and in what directory should I install them to? Does it matter? Should they be in the same directory as my game server files?

These all probably sound like dumb questions but im still learning and i'm hoping someone can help me out!

Answer (score 1):

You should simply try this command:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre
```

It will install OpenJDK JRE 7 into your *system*. Running a server should not require the JDK.